# Calculator in java,sin cos tan cot

Tags: java, calculator

The "switch case" witch I have write for sin,cos,tan,cot doesn't work when I enter them in operator and it goes to entering second number.
Where is my fault?
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner NumInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        double firstNum = 0;
        double secondNum = 0;
        double result = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        firstNum = NumInput.nextDouble() ;
        System.out.println("Enter operator: ");
        String amalgar = NumInput.next();
            if (amalgar == "sin" || amalgar == "cos" || amalgar == "tan" || amalgar == "cot"){
            switch(amalgar){
        case "sin":
            result = Math.toRadians(Math.sin(firstNum));
            break;
        case "cos":
            result = Math.toRadians(Math.cos(firstNum));
            break;
        case "tan":
            result = Math.toRadians(Math.tan(firstNum));
            break;
        case "cot":
            result = (Math.toRadians(Math.cos(firstNum))/Math.toRadians(Math.sin(firstNum)));
            break;

        default : 
            break;



            }
            System.out.println(Math.toRadians(result));
            }
            else

                System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
                secondNum = NumInput.nextDouble();  
            switch (amalgar){
        case "+":
            result = firstNum + secondNum;
            break;
        case "-":
            result = firstNum - secondNum;
            break;
        case "*":
            result = firstNum * secondNum;
            break;
        case "/":
            result = firstNum / secondNum;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("nemifahmam chi neveeshti");
        }

            System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with this if condition:

```
if (amalgar == "sin" || amalgar == "cos" || amalgar == "tan" || amalgar == "cot"){
```

Using `==` only evaluates to true if you have the same object (i.e. two identical references) but `"sin"`(or `"cos"`,etc) and `amalgar` are always two different objects. You should use `equals()` instead to compare the value. (see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java))

Better yet, don't use the if-else block at all. Use switch, because if you don't match one of those four you won't evaluate anything but your `default` case, which is empty.

Comment: for example : cos 0 = 1 but it shows me some thing like 3.48965,why?